# No sound from inbuilt speakers from dell inspiron 15 3542 series ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, google-chrome, dell

I have dell inspiron 15 3542 series laptop with ubuntu 12.04 as operating system.

Yesterday I had executed following commands from terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The above mentioned processes were successfully executed but when I did reboot ,there was no sound from inbuilt speakers on laptop.

After that I tried executing above commands and did reboot multiple times but the issue still persists.

Also I am receiving following notification in Google chrome browser

> This computer will soon stop receiving Google Chrome updates because
>   this Linux system will no longer be supported.

Looking forward for appropriate solution ASAP